# how do I do an insert with preperad statement passing a value of a subquery? And how to use a conditional value of the parameter?

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, prepared-statement

This consultation does not work
after adding the column sequence, before moving the query functioned normally.

I want to enter, make a select grabbing the maximum sequence column in the following section and add +1 and enter this value.

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
final StringBuilder lSql = new StringBuilder();
lSql.append(" INSERT INTO table1 ");
lSql.append(" ( column1, column2, column_sequence ) ");
lSql.append(" VALUES ");
lSql.append(" ( ?, ?,((select max(column_sequence )+1 from table1)) ");
    ...
```

therefore I plan to order values for specific groups where I need a conditional to collect a specific value as shown in the figure. I've realized search the oracle forum and analyzed the documentation, but the results of my research on this problem does not portray this cause.

[image]

**SEQUENCE USING THE TABLE DOES NOT APPLY:** The table has a sequence, but the order of business and this sequence is associated with a group of specific information it is not use sequence in a table. This value is repeated depending on a group of values that identify a column. For example, the bank statement when purchases are made in the same establishment, the identifier is repeated in the table in question, in consultation I am giving sequence for each store on the bank statement. Example: Store 1 - Buy 1,2,3 shop 2 - Buy 1,2,3. tavbela in the sequence shows how 1,2,3,4,5,6, for it serves not use the table sequence

Comment: Why no use a proper oracle sequence object for sequences?  Please show the code for your parameter setup.

Comment: The table has a sequence, but the order of business and this sequence is associated with a group of specific information it is not for use sequence in a table. This value is repeated depending on a group of values that identify a column. For example, the bank statement when purchases are made in the same establishment, the identifier is repeated in the table in question, in consultation I am giving sequence for each store on the bank statement. Example: Store 1 - Buy 1,2,3 shop 2 - Buy 1,2,3. tavbela in the sequence shows how 1,2,3,4,5,6, for it serves not use the table sequence